# Excel VBA How to insert picture of a file as a static/embedded picture

Tags: excel, vba

To insert a picture of a file into Excel, we can use `Insert` such as follow:

```
Activesheet.Pictures.Insert(<file path>)
```

But the picture will be inserted as a **linked picture**. Which means if I send the Excel file to another person, he/she wouldn't be able to see the picture as the link will appear broken.

[image]

I'm scracthing my head for a long time now, how do we add a picture not as a linked?

I also try breaking the link, but there seems no direct method for this as well.

My solution so far is `.CopyPicture`, then `.Paste` it again. That creates a static picture. But two problems, the picture quality degrades significantly (unacceptable), and the code will run slower right (OK if no choice).

Comment: Use `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture` instead

Comment: <3 <3 <3 I found it too... lol